# match length of string with a string with the same length in a list

Tags: python, string, match

So if I have this:

`a = "hi"

b = ["hello there", "goodbye", "nice to meet you"]`

so if the len(a) is 2 then is it possible to find a string with the same length in b? In this case is "hello there"

for "hi" I'm counting the characters but for "hello there" I'm counting the words.

I tried splitting the string:
`b = [["hello", "there"], "goodbye", "nice to meet you"]`
but I could only find a way to split them one by one

Comment: How does `"hello there"` have the same length as `"hi"`?

Comment: Sorry for "hi" I'm counting the characters but for "hello there" I'm counting the words...is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean that the **number of words** in the element of `b` should be the same as the **number of characters** in `a`:

```
a = "hi"
b = ["hello there", "goodbye", "nice to meet you"]

next(w for w in b if len(w.split()) == len(a))
# returns 'hello there'

[w for w in b if len(w.split()) == len(a)]
# returns ['hello there']
```